# Using Crop intent Getting java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4266ae80

Tags: android

I am using crop intent to crop the image,most of time it run fine,but sometime  getting java.lang.SecurityException: Unable    to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4266ae80

I attached logcat ,

```
08-07 11:33:21.190: I/BugSenseHandler(3337): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:33:21.230: I/BugSenseHandler(3337): Flushing...
08-07 11:33:21.230: I/BugSenseHandler(3337): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:33:25.104: D/AndroidRuntime(3629): Shutting down VM
08-07 11:33:25.104: W/dalvikvm(3629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41535700)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4266ae80 (pid=3629) when publishing content providers
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.publishContentProviders(ActivityManagerNative.java:2649)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4494)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-07 11:33:25.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 11:33:25.144: D/AndroidRuntime(3642): Shutting down VM
08-07 11:33:25.144: W/dalvikvm(3642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41535700)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642): java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@42508d78 (pid=3642) when publishing content providers
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.publishContentProviders(ActivityManagerNative.java:2649)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4494)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-07 11:33:25.144: E/AndroidRuntime(3642):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 11:33:25.184: W/Ads(3660): No Google Analytics: Library Incompatible.
08-07 11:33:25.244: D/dalvikvm(3660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 175K, 3% free 9014K/9216K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
08-07 11:33:25.244: I/dalvikvm-heap(3660): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.340MB for 3686416-byte allocation
08-07 11:33:25.254: D/dalvikvm(3660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 12614K/12820K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
08-07 11:33:25.384: D/dalvikvm(3660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 2% free 13584K/13780K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
08-07 11:33:25.514: I/Ads(3660): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("1D8E15EB640F879FCDCED4F201F62CAF");
08-07 11:33:25.524: V/GCMRegistrar(3660): Is registered on server: false
08-07 11:33:25.524: I/System.out(3660): registraion idAPA91bFQth1lFb5nVmxSWfeIkg3IDi9XsM3eJI9BvseFzE0ARi0QvZOTwSLu9b9muga5lttmg6eu9z4gbvfSo-1qQJLAqWbasGWm5s8RB8Yln4rGEXIs6VHcFzMyTbT0yrX1_jn0Lg-UWF74fXtlu0JGqTYOzZqDhg
08-07 11:33:25.534: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:33:25.534: D/dalvikvm(3660): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads1741195214.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
08-07 11:33:25.574: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Flushing...
08-07 11:33:25.584: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:33:25.605: D/libEGL(3660): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
08-07 11:33:25.605: D/libEGL(3660): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
08-07 11:33:25.605: D/dalvikvm(3660): DexOpt: --- END 'ads1741195214.jar' (success) ---
08-07 11:33:25.605: D/dalvikvm(3660): DEX prep '/data/data/com.app.bbq/cache/ads1741195214.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 69ms
08-07 11:33:25.605: D/libEGL(3660): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
08-07 11:33:25.615: I/Adreno200-EGL(3660): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
08-07 11:33:25.635: I/Ads(3660): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":0,"session_id":"6613293177245819931","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a151f0f89327fd9","u_w":384,"msid":"com.app.bbq","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"NTjh9Cwud64HgDL2o-CmkGYsbLqDs9is_xUOeGgUumJiL5rzIMo1PShh4L2A1hSFxgRGKhRw30DlrAsqrfHR7nBPMt0A8u-JoC-ssjqL6kdra-xezf6QxJCoxTOPWpjPF9TLhaF7KbAWiSxt9-eq-3ud3XffCiSfoL-BHnFQoYDzEqAvy5ydxDRFcKhasAAsYS4Wm4qEJQnBpEsDUq1Uc9PZhzfAAIRzrBXdc9xE-W7GBgJ6YCccYNnlqRu-bjIj2uwPQsHrs6e7D_WZmOgTf4ujDTUPFdCnT8a3d0kUH7DmDP3CJ-Xk6H6eEXQ_RYsx427_JAtQypAXnCwYtCkekQ","mv":"80220003.com.android.vending","isu":"1D8E15EB640F879FCDCED4F201F62CAF","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.app.bbq","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":0,"u_h":592,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":3});</script></head><body></body></html>
08-07 11:33:25.665: D/OpenGLRenderer(3660): Enabling debug mode 0
08-07 11:33:26.085: I/Ads(3660): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?kw&preqs=0&session_id=6613293177245819931&u_sd=2&seq_num=1&u_w=384&msid=com.app.bbq&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=NTjh9Cwud64HgDL2o-CmkGYsbLqDs9is_xUOeGgUumJiL5rzIMo1PShh4L2A1hSFxgRGKhRw30DlrAsqrfHR7nBPMt0A8u-JoC-ssjqL6kdra-xezf6QxJCoxTOPWpjPF9TLhaF7KbAWiSxt9-eq-3ud3XffCiSfoL-BHnFQoYDzEqAvy5ydxDRFcKhasAAsYS4Wm4qEJQnBpEsDUq1Uc9PZhzfAAIRzrBXdc9xE-W7GBgJ6YCccYNnlqRu-bjIj2uwPQsHrs6e7D_WZmOgTf4ujDTUPFdCnT8a3d0kUH7DmDP3CJ-Xk6H6eEXQ_RYsx427_JAtQypAXnCwYtCkekQ&mv=80220003.com.android.vending&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=1.android.com.app.bbq&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=3&u_so=p&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a151f0f89327fd9&kw_type=broad&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=xyFCSEpNJCce6O6eZQAM3JSBgQHhdly4clD4DEIyhfqgmUQG7xp7UiVUQuVcj9KW6c9lVlIt38A6HN5CNLGKXEVzdCwE6d4b--X9fAjhhQnCaHrGFS0q8e_NXQz8Tvxi&et=11&jsv=53" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
08-07 11:33:26.105: I/Ads(3660): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?kw&preqs=0&session_id=6613293177245819931&u_sd=2&seq_num=1&u_w=384&msid=com.app.bbq&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=NTjh9Cwud64HgDL2o-CmkGYsbLqDs9is_xUOeGgUumJiL5rzIMo1PShh4L2A1hSFxgRGKhRw30DlrAsqrfHR7nBPMt0A8u-JoC-ssjqL6kdra-xezf6QxJCoxTOPWpjPF9TLhaF7KbAWiSxt9-eq-3ud3XffCiSfoL-BHnFQoYDzEqAvy5ydxDRFcKhasAAsYS4Wm4qEJQnBpEsDUq1Uc9PZhzfAAIRzrBXdc9xE-W7GBgJ6YCccYNnlqRu-bjIj2uwPQsHrs6e7D_WZmOgTf4ujDTUPFdCnT8a3d0kUH7DmDP3CJ-Xk6H6eEXQ_RYsx427_JAtQypAXnCwYtCkekQ&mv=80220003.com.android.vending&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=1.android.com.app.bbq&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=3&u_so=p&imbf=9&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a151f0f89327fd9&kw_type=broad&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=xyFCSEpNJCce6O6eZQAM3JSBgQHhdly4clD4DEIyhfqgmUQG7xp7UiVUQuVcj9KW6c9lVlIt38A6HN5CNLGKXEVzdCwE6d4b--X9fAjhhQnCaHrGFS0q8e_NXQz8Tvxi&et=11&jsv=53
08-07 11:33:26.105: I/Ads(3660): Request scenario: Online server request.
08-07 11:33:26.525: D/dalvikvm(3660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 956K, 7% free 14204K/15184K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
08-07 11:33:26.525: D/webviewglue(3660): nativeDestroy view: 0x73ad2728
08-07 11:33:26.536: W/CursorWrapperInner(3660): Cursor finalized without prior close()
08-07 11:33:27.006: E/award Added(3660): award/8
08-07 11:33:27.016: E/award Added(3660): award/9
08-07 11:33:27.026: E/award Added(3660): award/10
08-07 11:33:27.036: E/award Added(3660): award/11
08-07 11:33:27.046: E/award Added(3660): award/12
08-07 11:33:27.056: E/award Added(3660): award/13
08-07 11:33:27.066: E/award Added(3660): award/14
08-07 11:33:27.757: D/webviewglue(3660): nativeDestroy view: 0x73ad27b0
08-07 11:33:27.757: I/Ads(3660): onReceiveAd()
08-07 11:33:27.797: D/TilesManager(3660): Starting TG #0, 0x766f0880
08-07 11:33:27.797: D/TilesManager(3660): new EGLContext from framework: 75ef3328 
08-07 11:33:27.797: D/GLWebViewState(3660): Reinit shader
08-07 11:33:27.837: D/GLWebViewState(3660): Reinit transferQueue
08-07 11:33:30.269: I/GAV2(3660): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
08-07 11:35:38.957: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:35:38.987: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Flushing...
08-07 11:35:38.987: I/BugSenseHandler(3660): Registering default exceptions handler
08-07 11:35:39.978: D/dalvikvm(3660): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1427K, 10% free 14561K/16012K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This log means that your app is having trouble handling a communication intent. Sometimes problems like this can occur when you send intent with very big extras.

Passing High resolution photos or big file via extras is not recommended, the best practice is to save the file on the external storage (if you haven't done it yet), get a `Uri` reference to it and send this ref as String in your intent's extra

`yourIntent.putExtra("MyUriKey", yourUri.toString)`

If you are dealing with an image and quality is not of your concern, you can use a workaround and simply reduce the file's dimension by compressing it.

Comment: it comes when I choose image from album or take image from camera.

Comment: @Ravi how do you take those image? As an Uri or as a Bitmap?

Comment: I get this for trying to send a 200KB e-mail :|

Comment: @RobertoLombardini: I am having same problem. I am taking it as bitmap.. please help.. When I crop the image and setting it onto ImageView then it gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i was passing a byteArray of a bitmap in a intent. 
After seeing Roberto Lombardini's answer, I changed my code so that it could send the uri of the bitmap instead, and my problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Roberto Lombardini's answer.
Maybe you can try this solution for simple reference.

1. Save your bitmap into local first with unique name or you own resource id, you can use UUID

   ```
   public void savePhotoCache(final String resourceId, final Bitmap bitmap) {
       if(bitmap==null)
           return;

       File imageDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images/yourpackagename");
       if (!imageDir.isDirectory())
           imageDir.mkdirs();

       File cachedImage = new File(imageDir, resourceId);
       FileOutputStream output = null;
       try {
           output = new FileOutputStream(cachedImage);
           bitmap.compress(PNG, 100, output);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("CACHED_IMAGE", "Exception writing cache image", e);
       } finally {
           if (output != null)
               try {
                   output.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // Ignored
               }
       }
   }
   ```
2. When passing to another activity you only pass resource id and get bitmap data in another activity using this function.

   ```
   private Bitmap getPhotoCache(final String resourceId) {
       File imageDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images/yourpackagename");
       if (!imageDir.isDirectory())
           imageDir.mkdirs();

       File imageFile = new File(imageDir, resourceId);

       if (!imageFile.exists() || imageFile.length() == 0)
           return null;

       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
       if (bitmap != null)
           return bitmap;
       else {
           imageFile.delete();
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

I hope this can help you. :)